# Meaning of Middle High German "uñ"

Tags: abbreviation, middle-high-german

In translating some of the Middle High German of the *Carmina Burana*, my edition (piano/vocal edition of Orff's settings published by Schott, 1996) has the following verse:

> Suzer rosenvarwer munt,
>   chum uñ mache mich gesunt.

I believe I read somewhere that this was a scribal abbreviation for "und/unde", but I can't remember where and can't find this information again. It would make sense, yielding:

> Süßer rosenfarbener Mund,
>   komm und mach mich gesund.

Is this correct? I would also love any references (online or otherwise) confirming this if possible.

*ed.: fixed my adjective declension and inserted source edition*

Comment: Sounds good, except for rosenfarbe, that should be *rosenfarbener* =color of a rose (not necessarily the same as *ros**a**farben* =pink).

Comment: I am not an expert, but immediately after reading the title I thought that it probably means *und[e]* (or *unt[e]*). It's very obviously the word missing here, and squiggles above letters to indicate that something following has been dropped is just what medieaval scribes did. This is also how ä for ae, ö for oe, ü for ue came up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice to tell us your sources too.

Generally speaking I would agree. *uñ* is surely translated with *und*.

Yet after some googeling I found some other versions of your quote:

http://turba-delirantium.skyrocket.de/bibliotheca/carmina-burana_cb174a.htm

```
Suozer roservarwer munt,
chum vnde mache mich gesunt!
chum vnde mache mich gesunt,
suozer roservarwer munt!
```

is according to that page translated like:

```
Süsser, rosafarbener Mund,
komm und mache mich gesund,
komm und mache mich gesund,
Süsser, rosafarbener Mund.
```

Yet they weren't using your variant so I had to search for the original which seems to be on Google Books (Bibliothek des Literarischen Vereins in Stuttgart, Literarischer Verein in Stuttgart., 1847): https://books.google.kg/books?id=e6osAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA209&dq=%22chum+un+mache+mich+gesunt%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=R6RZVa2pGom8swGdyYDoCQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22chum%20un%20mache%20mich%20gesunt%22&f=false

[image: Bibliothek des Literarischen Vereins in Stuttgart, Literarischer Verein in Stuttgart., 1847]

There seems to be a version by the German composer Carl Orff who translated *un* with *und* as well. Yet his writing it without the tilde. Probably only for reasons to write it less confusing.

https://www.atanet.org/publications/beacons_10_pages/page_68.pdf uses *unde* instead of *vnde* - which is only due to the Latin similarity of *u* and *v*. (Like the first version in this post)

It's difficult to say which which version is the "original" facsimile from the first text which appeared. I imagine it might be either *vnde* or *un* - just for practical uses.

Comment: You say "Generally speaking I would agree." Out of curiosity, what are some other possibilities that "uñ" could stand for?

Comment: In the Middle Ages it was customary to write a _u_ at the beginning of a word as _v_. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U#History) (and the fact that Latin only had _v_) explains _vnd[e]_. As for the [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde), it was widely used to stand for omitted characters, in this case the _d_.